# Cannot assign key to blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I am trying to upload photos to the blobstore. My code is similar to the example [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers#BlobstoreUploadHandler)

```
class Image(ndb.Model):
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    user = ndb.UserProperty()
    blob_key = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
```

In my UploadHandler I do the following:

```
blob_info = self.get_uploads('file')[0]
image = Image()
image.user = users.get_current_user()
image.blob_key = blob_info.key()
```

However, that last line always results in the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

This is driving me crazy. I can upload the picture, but I can't store the key! Anybody know what might be wrong?

Comment: Maybe this works, because of a mismatch between an ndb blobkey and the blobstore blobkey: image.blob_key = str(blob_info.key())

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried it, but it didn't work either. Still getting the same TypeError.

Comment: In ndb you save the blob_key in a BlobKeyProperty gives for your model: blob_key = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()

Comment: That's what I was looking for, but I couldn't find it anywhere. Now it's working! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You will have t revert your data model to db if you want to use BlobReferenceProperty, its not very clearly documented, if you really want to use ndb you need to use BlobKeyProperty as mentioned by voscausa. I personally find the db model simpler to use than ndb and don't really get the hype round ndb

```
class Image(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    blob_key = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
```